# Удаление пробелов из url между тегами в PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

**Имеется текст**

> Привет как дела ? у меня все хорошо, заходи на сайт [url]http:// wwww. web - site .com [/url] или этот [url]http:// wwww. website2 .com [/url]
>   Сегодня хорошая погода ? не правдо ли ? Верно, пишите на емайл [at]myemail@mail. com[/at] или [at]myemail2@mail. com[/at]

Задача состоит в том, что бы убрать пробелы в выше приведенных тегах, но не операясь на кол-во ссылок и их имена (так как имена ссылок и емайлов не известны, но они все маркируются данными тегами `[url]` и `[at]`, что облегчает их поиск).

**Результат должен быть таков**

> Привет как дела ? у меня все хорошо, заходи на сайт [url]http://www.web-site.com[/url] или этот [url]http://wwww.website2.com[/url]
>   Сегодня хорошая погода ? не правдо ли ? Верно, пишите на емайл [at]myemail@mail.com[/at] или [at]myemail2@mail.com[/at]

Как это сделать на PHP?

Comment: А почему регулярные выражения? Может быть брать текст, находить тег....все что с начала тега до конца тега `str_replace(" ","",$str)`

Comment: А как сам пытался?

Comment: Как я понимаю без, перебора массива не обойтись ? Если сможете подкорректировать данное регулярное выражение   <url[^>]*>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/url>   сдесь находит тег <url> а мне нужно [url] , подкоректируйте пожалуйсто

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str="Привет как дела ? у меня все хорошо, заходи на сайт [url]http:// wwww. web - site .com [/url] или этот [url]http:// wwww. website2 .com [/url] Сегодня хорошая погода ? не правдо ли ? Верно, пишите на емайл [at]myemail@mail. com[/at] или [at]myemail2@mail. com[/at]";
print preg_replace('/(\[(url|at)]|(?!^)\G)[^[]*?\K +(?=.*?\[\/(url|at)])/','',$str);
```

Единственное текущее ограничение регулярки - url внутри тегов не должен содержать `[` (т.е. не может быть ссылок вида: `[url]www. [ abc.com[/url]`). Если они могут присутствовать, придется усложнять.

Пример на [101regex.com](https://regex101.com/r/iK9lK8/1)

Если регулярка кажется слишком сложной, можно воспользоваться подходом с выделением части внутри тегов и замены пробелов callback функцией (разумеется для тегов `[url]` и `[at]`):

```
print preg_replace_callback('/\[(url|at)].*?\[\/\1]/',
                            function($txt) { return str_replace(' ','',$txt[0]); },
                            $str);
```

Comment: @StackOverFollow Предлагаю почистить комментарии, а то какая то простыня набралась, не особо нужная будущим поколениям. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2408/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Привет как дела ? у меня все хорошо, заходи на сайт [url]http:// wwww. web - site .com [/url] или этот [url]http:// wwww. website2 .com [/url] Сегодня хорошая погода ? не правдо ли ? Верно, пишите на емайл [at]myemail@mail. com[/at] или [at]myemail2@mail. com[/at]';

$pattern = '/\[[a-z]{2,3}\](.*?)\[\/[a-z]{2,3}\]/';

preg_match_all($pattern,$str, $arr);

foreach ($arr[1] as $value) {
    $pattern[] = "[".$value."]";
    $tmp[] = str_replace(' ', '', $value);

}


$str = preg_replace($pattern, $tmp, $str);

print($str);
```

Comment: Почему закрывающие квадратные скобки не экранированы?

Comment: да вроде проверку прошла в конструкторе

Comment: Пожалуйста, экранируйте все спецсимволы, раз уж начали

Comment: Все хорошо, только вот текста нет, в результате. А только ссылки.

Comment: @StackOverFollow, обновил код